# Use And Import .SO Native Library From Apk In Python

Tags: python, linux, ctypes, decompiler, android-native-library

How do I import and use an `.SO` file that I extracted from `apk` file?
I've used ctypes library in Linux but it gave me error on every way I tried it.

There are 2 version of the `.so` files: arm64, and armeabi.
When i tried import the armeabi version, which is 32-bit, it gave me

```
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

and so I try the arm64, and somehow I got

```
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can assure you it is not a typo path, I tried to copy it using the same path. but I cannot import it because no such file.

code:

```
import ctypes

def main():

     TestLib = ctypes.CDLL('/home/manalkaff/Desktop/arm64-v8a/nativelibrary.so')

if __name__ == '__main__':

     main()
```

Is this how I am supposed to do it? Or there is another way?

Comment: What type of computer are you using to run this code? Do you have ARM CPU?

Comment: @kichik nope, i used virtual box since i cant do it in windows, and i have `x86_64` cpu architecture

Comment: You can't load and execute ARM code in a x86 process. You need a virtual machine that emulates ARM CPU.

Comment: how am i not aware of this, thank you so much. that clear thing out. and after i import that can i use the function that the apk's using too?

Comment: Maybe. It might be missing dependencies from Android. You can check it with `ldd my.so` once you're on ARM Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't load and execute ARM code on x86 CPU. You need a virtual machine that will emulate ARM CPU for that.

Even after loading the `.so` file on Linux ARM, you might still be missing some Android dependencies. Use `ldd copied.so` to see which.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to decompile and port your shared object to x86. To do this you should load your binary in Ghidra and extract all the functions except utility ones like JNI initialization etc. which will be inserted by compiler automatically if required. Then rebuild using compiler and IDE of your choice like Clion + Clang. Not forget to fix some errors and switch to Windows API if Android API was used. This will require some time and effort though, depending on amount of functions and size of binary (except support stuff once again).